# Ajax Response: [readyState: 0, responseText: “”, status: 0, statusText: “error”]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having problems in submitting the form with file in Firefox v40 and up, it returns a response: `[readyState: 0, responseText: “”, status: 0, statusText: “error”]`

here is my code:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // bind to the form's submit event
    //grab all form data  
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(result);
            processDepositResponse(formId, result);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(formId + '.loading-icon').remove();
            $(formId).prepend("<div class='flash error'>There was an error in processing your request. Please try again.</div>");
            $(formId + '#confirmBtn').prop('disabled', false);
        } 

    });
    return false;
});
```

I use the `ajaxSubmit` because I am posting a form with file to server.

Please take note that this is not happening in Chrome nor in lower version of firefox(version 35 and below) and the issue was intermittent meaning that sometimes it is submitting the form, sometimes it's not.

I just want to know what is causing this intermittent issue. thanks in advance

**Update**
It seems that firefox is aborting the request when we look in the browser console.

Comment: are you using seperate plugin for ajaxSubmit(). I guess it does not come with jquery core plugin.Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: ajaxSubmit is not a jquery function, please write the definition for this function.

Comment: Updated my code so it doesn't use the Ajax submit. but i'll update and add the ajax submit once i'll finish the fiddle.